# Styling the first 10 items in a list

Tags: css

Can something like li:nth-child be used to style the first ten items in a list?

```
<ol>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
  <li>item 8</li>
  <li>item 9</li>
  <li>item 10</li>
  <li>item 11</li>
  <li>item 12</li>
</ol>
```

so 1 to 10 will be fancy and 11 and 12 will be normal. 
I'd rather not use a class if possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

nth childs example:

```
:nth-child(-n+10)
```

this in works here: [link](http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/).

more on understanding this check out this [site](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/).

---

I guess if you want IE support, i can't really make this any prettier. Atleast I don't know how with this cheap hack.

```
ul>li + li + li + li + li + li + li + li + li + li + li{
    text-align: center; /*makes everything after 10 centered*/

}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TzLqZ/ for an example of this above

---

Here is the IE way with first 10 being center and the last 2 being normal:
http://jsfiddle.net/TzLqZ/3/

```
ol>li{
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
}
ol>li+li+li+li+li+li+li+li+li+li+li
{
    text-align: left;
    color: red;
}
```

​

​

Comment: @JohnRiselvato oops didn't notice your post ***again*** as I was editing mine. Want to try and race for a third method? ;)

Comment: I can't think of a 3rd method? using only nth-child that is.

Comment: @Hawken created a IE supported :D

Comment: @JohnRiselvato I guess you win. Where on earth did you learn that?

Comment: Well i knew that > give a direct child of an element. I was taking a leap of faith with the `+ li + li` business. Luckily it sort of works.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for the nth child pseudo-selector seen here http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/
I think for what what you want to do:

select all but top ten:

```
ul li:nth-child(n+11){}
```

or just top ten:

```
ul li:nth-child(-n+10){}
```

should do the trick.

**However**, Internet Explorer does **not** support this at least until ie8 according to the article. So don't rely on it for anything critical (although I don't know what child specific styling would be *critical*).

Comment: there are better ways to take advantage of nth-child.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato **Editied** found that just before you posted your comment :)